# Generate iCal invite and open native calendar?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, icalendar

I know you can use `calshow:\(date)` to open the native calendar from an app for the selected date, but I don't see a way to add a title or description for the event.

Is it possible to generate an `iCal` invite on the fly in Swift and open it within the app so native calendar opens for it?

Comment: Why not use EventKit/EventKitUI framework and create calendar events without leaving your app?

Comment: I want to keep it simple and not go into extra permissions of full fledged calendar integration. I'm really just displaying an appointment for them to tap on.

Comment: You can use EventKit/EventKitUI framework to create calendar even and open calendar app after event creation.